# Removing CDATA from xml response

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd

One attribute called Response is defined in my webservice via this XSD schema definition:

```
<xs:element name="Response" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
```

Inside this response, the Java code of the webService inserts some XLM content.

This is what I want:

```
<Response>
    <A>a</A>
    <B>b</B>
</Response>
```

But, this is what I get:

```
<Response><![CDATA[<A>a</A><B>b</B>]]></Response>
```

Also, I have noticed that a LoggingHandler outputs:

```
<Response>
    &lt;A>a&lt;/A&gt;&#13;
    &lt;B>b&lt;/B&gt;&#13;
</Response>
```

Is there a way to avoid that CDATA?

Thanks

Comment: Who/what is consuming this XML response?  Presumably there is a reason why the service is giving you the response you see.

Comment: The content of the ``Response`` node is defined as a ``xs:string``, that's what leads to a CDATA block since the string contains xml entities. Can you adapt your schema?

Comment: Oh, I see that CDATA testing with SoapUI

Comment: If your Java code isn't doing what you want it to do, then it is wrong, and if you show us the code then we can probably tell you how to fix it. But fixing bugs in code that you haven't seen is hard.